# While save binary data into table I'm getting NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Here I'm trying to upload a file into database, but I'm getting `NULL` in my db

Please give me any hint.

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

foreach(string file in httpRequest.Files) 
{
    var postedfile = httpRequest.Files[file];
    var FileName = httpPostedFile.FileName;
    int fileSize = httpPostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[fileSize];
    httpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(fileByteArray, 0, fileSize);
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[file];
    byte[] bytes;

    using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream)) 
    {
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
    }
    Temp_Table = new Temp_Table {
        Profiledata = bytes
    };
    db.Table.Add(_temp);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I'm surprised this code would even compile. You have the variable postedFile declared twice.

Comment: there's a hint - use the debugger and check where the things go wrong. Also, work on your code style. Also, what is `_temp` - this is never declared.

Comment: @Steve C# is case sensitive. var postedfile = lowercase f, HttpPostedFile postedFile = uppercase F. Thats why it compiles

Comment: I always try to avoid saving actual files into a database, I usually save the file path to the database and the file within that path. Maybe you could try this instead?